# Django: search_device_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Tags: django, templates, compiler-errors

I have a search page that was working until I coded in the return of the search for editing.
Ideally, the user does a search and it returns some values, all good so far.  Then when the user clicks on the edit button for a value I want the fields to return in an editable format.

Here is the views.py

```
def search_device_list(request, id):
     license_key = Maintenance.objects.get(id=id)
     maintenance_form = MaintenanceForm(instance=license_key) 
     devices = Devices.objects.filter(maintenance = id)
     end_of_maintenance_support = MaintenanceForm()

     locations = Locations.objects.all()
     context ={"locations": locations}

     for locations in context['locations']:
        print(locations)

     if request.method == 'POST':
         location_name=request.POST.get('location_name')
         my_devices = Devices.objects.filter(locations = Locations.objects.get(location_name = location_name))
         maintenance_form = MaintenanceForm(request.POST, instance=license_key)
         license_key = request.POST.get('license_key')
         maintenance_support_end_date = request.POST.get('maintenance_support_end_date')

         context["devices"]= my_devices   
         context["location_name"]= location_name  
         context["license_key"] = license_key
         context["maintenance_support_end_date"] = maintenance_support_end_date

         if maintenance_form.is_valid(): 
            license = maintenance_form.save()
            print (license.license_key)

            postdevices= request.POST.getlist("devices")
            for device_hostname in postdevices:
                device = Devices.objects.get(device_hostname = device_hostname)
                print(device.maintenance.license_key)
                print(device.maintenance.maintenance_support_end_date)
                device.save()

     return render(request, 'inventory/search_device_list.html', context)
```

Here is the template.py

```
{% block content %} 

<h2 align="left">Search Page</h2>

<!-- <form action="{% url 'inventory:render_results' %}" method="POST" > -->
<form action="{% url 'inventory:search_device_list' %}" method="POST" >

{% csrf_token %}  
<body>
<table class=table> 
<tr>
    <td><b>Locations: &nbsp;&nbsp; </b></td>
    <td>
    <select name="location_name">
    {% for locations in locations %} 
    <option value="{{locations.location_name}}">{{locations.location_name}}</option>{% endfor%}
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>
<br>

<h3 align="left">Render Device List based on Location Choice</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Locations:</b><br>{{location_name }} <br></td>
        <td><b> Devices: </b><br>
        {% for device in devices %}{{device.device_hostname}} <br>{% endfor %}  </td>

        <td id="maintenance_support_end_date"><b>End of Maintenance Support:</b><br>{% for device in devices%}{{device.maintenance.maintenance_support_end_date}}<br> {% endfor %}  </td>   
        <td id="license_key"><b>License Key:</b><br>{% for device in devices%}{{device.maintenance.license_key}}<br>{% endfor %}</td>
        <td><b>Actions:</b><br> {% for device in devices%} <a href= {% url 'inventory:search_device_list' %}><button id="maintenance_support_end_date">Edit </button></a><br> {% endfor %}  </td>   

    </tr>   
</table>

<table class=table> 
<h3 align="left"> Edit Table </h3>
<tr>
    <td><b>Locations:&nbsp;</b></td><td>{{maintenance_form.location_name}}</td>
    <td><b>Devices&nbsp;</b></td><td>{% if devices %} 
                {% for device in devices %} 
                    {{ device }} <br><br> 
                {% endfor %} </td>
    <td><b>License Key:&nbsp;</b></td><td>{{maintenance_form.license_key}}</td>
    <td><b>Support End Date:&nbsp;</b></td><td>{{maintenance_form.maintenance_support_end_date}}</td>   
</tr>
</table>

 {% endblock content %}
```

And finally, the urls.py - I did do some searches on this error message, as it's a common one, so I tried two different url paths

```
     url(r'^search_device_list/$', views.search_device_list, name='search_device_list'), 
     url(r'^search_device_list/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.search_device_list, name='search_device_list'),
```

Two different models are being referenced here, the Devices as well as the Maintenance.  And I think this is a flaw in my understanding of how the id is being passed through the code.  Any ideas or hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Change

`def search_device_list(request, id):`

To

`def search_device_list(request, id=None):`

Note that you'll have to modify your code so that it handles the case when `id` *is* `None`, as currently, your view is dependent on that `id` being given.

### Explanation

Both `/search_device_list/` and `/search_device_list/(?P<id>\d+)` uses the same view.

When you access the first URL, it calls your view function, but doesn't pass an `id`.

When you access the `/search_device_list/(?P<id>\d+)`, it calls your view function, but this time it passes an `id`.

By having changing the view function to `def search_device_list(request, id=None):`, you are making the `id` parameter of your view function optional

Comment: Thank you so much; Now I am getting an error "Maintenance matching query does not exist." and this is for "license_key = Maintenance.objects.get(id=id)"  and this is because the ID is now "None" .  Since when I'm editing I am coming back to the page with "id" in hand if you will, so it should not be "None".  I've been looking for examples of this type of code "in the works" as I know that web pages do this all of the time.  Would you be able to point me in the direction of a sample or full explanation?

Comment: Sure, but I suggest you mark this question as resolved and post another with the new issue and updated code. Link the new question here and I'll answer it as well  @MarthaV